# RxJS - reusing an observable which has completed

Tags: rxjs

[Link to code in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-sxahp7)

Is there a way to repeat a completed observable multiple times?

Say I have a button that on click creates an interval observable that emits 10 values, then completes:

```
fromEvent(button, 'click').pipe(
    switchMapTo(interval(500)),
    takeWhile(i => i < 10)
)
```

In the subscription I want to handle both the next and the complete methods:

```
.subscribe(
    i => console.log(i),
    () => {},
    () => console.log('completed')
);
```

In this way - the first click will emit one sequence and once it completes, subsequent clicks will not emit again. Is there any way to write this so that all clicks emit the sequence?

Comment: One observer can receive always only one `complete` notification. You could use `repeat()` operator but then you will never see receive any `complete` notification.

Comment: @martin could we use `finalize` to catch `complete` before the `repeat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should complete the inner observable and not the whole sequence.
(takeWhile should be piped to interval);

You should use `switchMap` only if you are happy to dismiss the old sequence once a new click event comes in. `mergeMap` or `concatMap` otherwise.

```js
const sequence = () => interval(500).pipe(take(10));

fromEvent(button, 'click').pipe(
    switchMap(sequence),
)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works with minor tweaks:
`const sequence = () => interval(500).pipe(take(10),finalize(() => console.log('completed')));

fromEvent(button, 'click').pipe(switchMapTo(sequence())).subscribe(console.log);`

Comment: if you directly call `sequence()` you create the observable when you define your pipe and not when the user clicks. so, change `switchMapTo(sequence())` with `switchMap(sequence)`.